# How do I recover drivers from other hard disk

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

The drivers for a Cardbus (PCMCIA) card that gives me 2 USB 2.0 ports are on the hard disk from my old laptop. I have lost the driver CD. I have a way to get files from that other hard disk. Which files do I need?

The drivers for the card used to be on the following website - the information is still there, except the download links don't work: http://www.ht-link.com/en/DownView.asp?ID=10  - The drivers I need are the first listing - The Win XP drivers for the HT-112NEC.  My e-mails to them have not been answered. The information on this card is here http://www.ht-link.com/en/ProductView.asp?ID=106

I already tried connecting that other drive to my new laptop (via USB) and adding the drive to the search criteria when selecting update driver in the Device Manager.  It says there isn't a better match, and if I select manual the matching device is not listed. (I don't think "manual" sees drivers on the external hard disk -  but only ones on the main drive and/or found listed in the registry.)  I would try 'have disk' if I knew exactly what file to point to on the external drive.  The drivers are on that hard disk - I installed them there, and used that card on that computer.

The new laptop has Windows XP Pro SP3, the old one had Pro SP2

Thanks for any help.

---

Update: I searched e:\windows (sub directories, including system files & hidden files) for any .inf files containing "ht-link," and there were no matches.

---

Update: I used a utility to see what files were different between c:\Windows\System32\drivers and that directory on e:. I still can't tell which files might be the drivers. I copied the following files from drive e: (that didn't exist on c:) - hidusb.sys, usbccgp.sys, usbprint.sys, usbscan.sys, and wpdusp.sys. Selecting manual driver selection in the Device Manager revealed no new options.  Those are probably SP2 files, replaced in SP3, or I don't know what they are.

Comment: Not an answer, just an alternate, but have you looked at driverguide.com to see if anyone has posted your drivers?  Might be an alternative solution.

Comment: I tried driverquide.com. It's not there. I also can't create an account there - there are no links for the three sign-up options. I e-mailed them about that and I got a canned response that they were sorry the driver I was looking for wasn't there, and to post a request for the driver I need (I need an account to do that).

Comment: The driverguide page is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manufacturer sent me the driver.  It was in Windows\System32\drivers on my external disk - now I know which one it was.

Answer (score 0):

Your drivers will be located in `C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had already figured that much out. There are 229 files in that directory. I tried adding Company to the detailed files view, and sorted on that. There are no files where Company = HT-Link.

Comment: Take them all, it will not hurt your computer to have extras that are not used.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the old drive to boot, then there are plenty of tools to backup and restore drivers. I've used [Double Driver](http://www.boozet.org/dd.htm) before.

Comment: The old drive doesn't fit in my new laptop. It's the right size, and the pins are right, there's just this piece of plastic next to the pins that keeps it from fitting. I don't have a working computer it will fit in.  My laptop won't boot from a USB connected hard disk.

Comment: If the BIOS doesn't support USB booting you can load grub from a liveCD (the linux bootloader), and then you should be able to chain-load windows from there. To be honest, it's probably less work finding the drivers for the card online.