# Can I recover files and drivers from a C drive used as an external,for a fresh install of new SSD and O/S

Tags: file-recovery, fresh-install

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recover drivers from other hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/142717/how-do-i-recover-drivers-from-other-hard-disk)

**Some background**: I have had a major crash of `C` drive, will boot in safe mode and w/ networking rom
Nothing has worked to restore and a very recent `ISO` back up failed multiple times.
I have decided to replace this drive and do a fresh install of Windows 7 pro from new DVD, new drive being `OCZ Vertex SATA 3 480gb Sandforce 2281`.

**Here is my question**

Will I be able to access `system32` files, search for drivers and remove needed personal files from this replaced `C` drive onto and from the new SSD one its installed. If I make the removed `C` drive an external drive and connect it to the computer.

Any help/advice in this area, in making sure all data is not hidden files etc.  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to edit your post but unfortunately its not too much clear to me. Well, I did some cleanup to look it better but if you could explain your problem more clearly then it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The short answer is: Yes you can, see the link above. But you will get the driver which where previously installed. Not the most up to date ones. If you previous installation was not recently done it might be better to download the newest drivers.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to access the files on your old hard drive, if the
   data is not corrupt and if the hard drive itself is not physically
   damaged.
2. If you are using Windows to read files from your old C drive, you should
   be wary of permissions issues with NTFS ACLs. You may need to reset
   the ACLs using a utility such as Microsoft's `icacls`. Alternatively,
   you could just use a Linux Live CD to move the files from your old
   hard drive to your new hard drive.
3. As for hidden files, if you are using Windows, you can set your
   Windows Explorer options to show hidden and system files. If you are
   using Linux, hidden files an NTFS partition should be visible by
   default.
4. Normally, your files and settings should all be within your user
   profile folder, and you should not have to worry about files in
   `system32`. To install drivers, you should use the latest installer
   executable from the manufacturer, instead of trying to retrieve
   driver files from the old filesystem.